# Cannot change the color of column chart according to its value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, chart.js

I need to implement this code exactly using it. Here is my code example:

```
 barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
        responsive: true,
    };
    barChartColors: Color[] = [
        {
        backgroundColor: 'forestgreen',
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 3
    }, {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 3
    }];
    barChartLabels: Label[] = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15',
        '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'];
    barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
    barChartLegend = false;
    barChartPlugins = [];

    barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
        {
            data: [11, 12, 12, 14, 14, 19, 22, 28, 29, -30, 31, 31, 35, 35, 35, -37, 37, 40, 40, 41, 45, 45, 48, 51, 57,
                62, 65, 69, 69, 71, 75]
        }
    ];
```

This is my HTML side of the code but it is not working:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper" style="width: 100%">
                    <canvas baseChart
                            [colors]="barChartData>0 ? barChartColors[0] : barChartColors[1]"
                            [datasets]="barChartData"
                            [labels]="barChartLabels"
                            [options]="barChartOptions"
                            [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
                            [legend]="barChartLegend"
                            [chartType]="barChartType">
                    </canvas>
                </div>
```

**[colors]="barChartData>0 ? barChartColors[0] : barChartColors[1]"** this row gave me this mistake:

1. *Type Color is not assignable to type Color[]*
2. *DashboardComponent.barChartData: ChartDataSets[]*
3. *DashboardComponent.barChartColors: Color[]*

Also, compiler give me to this:

**Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'ChartDataSets[]' and 'number'.[colors]="barChartData>0 ? barChartColors['forestgreen'] : barChartColors['red']"**

Could you help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`barChartData` is an array of `ChartDataSets` that contains a single element. Therefore, to make it work, you could change your code as follows:

```
[colors]="barChartData[0].data.map(v => v > 0 ? barChartColors[0] : barChartColors[1])"
```

or more compact...

```
[colors]="barChartData[0].data.map(v => barChartColors[v > 0 ? 0 : 1])"
```

> This code uses [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), on the `data` array inside `ChartDataSets`. It returns a new `array` with the appropriate color for each value.